# PHP string to array conversion error

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a php string `$data`.
on `echo $data;` I get

```
{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"4","_version":10,"created":false}
```

I want the string to split in array. So that,

```
$data["_index"]=movies etc.
```

I tried `$data=array($data);`
but got `Array ( [0] => {"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"4","_version":10,"created":false} )`
How to correctly obtain array.

Comment: `$array = json_decode($data, true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is JSON.  Just use `json_decode`:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($array);
```